# Where is "Port Mirroring" on VMware vSphere?

Tags: esxi, mirroring

I am using VMware vSphere 5.5.0, but I cannot find "Port Mirroring".

According to [this link](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.networking.doc%2FGUID-42C0D7D4-E0DB-462D-BC49-4E8464B6E2F5.html):

1. Log in to the vSphere Client and select the Networking inventory view.
2. Right-click the vSphere distributed switch in the inventory pane, and select Edit Settings.

However, the switch is unable to right-click. Nothing comes out when I right-click it.

Comment: From your other question, you indicated you were using vSphere 5.5, so which version are you using?

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, it is 5.5